# How to get current seller id

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection

I written `Product collection` but i can't able to get current seller id

```
public function getMy(){


        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //add product attribute to be fetched
        $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
        $collection->getSelect()->limit(5);
        //$collection->addAttributeToFilter('seller_id');
        $collection->addStoreFilter();
        return $collection;

    }
```

My problem is i want to display other product of same seller in product details page, So how to get **Current seller id**

```
Mage::getModel ( 'marketplace/sellerprofile' )
```

Comment: maybe ... `addAttributeToSelect` instead of to filter?

Answer (score 1):

current seller will be customer id of current user. and you can get it with below code

```
public function getMy(){

if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
         $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
          $seller_id= $customerData->getId();
     }
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //add product attribute to be fetched
        $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
        $collection->getSelect()->limit(5);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter($seller_id);
        $collection->addStoreFilter();
        return $collection;

    }
```

Comment: How to get in collection

Comment: updated the code............................

Comment: what doubt you have?

Comment: query fetch more then 200 record i worte that collection in phtml it will take time to load in front end

Comment: off course 200 record will take time. For that  you add pagination

Comment: I tried this but it's not working it's not fetch seller id

Comment: did seller  login or not?

Comment: No i want without login let assume if customer open a product that product have A selller i want to display other product of A Seller

Comment: seller in attribute for it is related to product in some other table

Comment: $sellerId      = Mage::registry('current_product')->getSellerId();

 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
 $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //add product attribute to be fetched
 $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter('seller_id',$sellerId);
 $collection->addStoreFilter();

Comment: i used in phtml it's working fine but i want to use in block how i used

Comment: you are using it in product view page?

Comment: in above code i am using view page your code i am using block file

Comment: block also used in product view page??

Comment: Yes But it's not working

Comment: try that `$proid = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id'); 
$pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($proid);
$sellerId = $pro->getSellerId(); 
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection'); $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //add product attribute to be fetched $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()'); $collection->addAttributeToFilter('seller_id',$sellerId); $collection->addStoreFilter();`

Comment: in phtml <?php $collection = $this->getMy();?> this right

Comment: yep that is correct

Comment: But no luck.....

Comment: `echo $proid = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id'); ` and check you are getting he id or not.and this code will work on product view page

Comment: Ya it's printing id

Comment: debug it and check the product id is loading and load seller id too

Comment: I need to write this method block files right

Comment: yes this is basic bro you must understand that

Comment: Yes i know i wrote there only only but it's not working so that i am asking

Comment: you the product is loading and give data check print_r($pro->getData()); check seller id is there

Comment: Okay thanks for your help i try my end and let you know